# Flutter simple background timer example

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background

I am trying to understand how to write a simple background timer in Flutter...

I need an EditText where I write the time and simple button that sets the notification event on a scheduled time.

For example: I set the time at 08.00pm in the EditText, now It's 07.30pm; I tap the button; a timer of a 30 minutes has started in background.

When this timer has terminated a notification is displayed on my OS.

How can I write it?
Is there any way to write it for both Android and IOS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

https://github.com/lohanidamodar/flutter_achiver

I have created a open source pomodoro timer and tracker, currently only implemented on Android, but should work on iOS with few tweaks. It works as you requested,

1. Allows user to create a project and set the work time duration
2. Once user starts the timer, a notification is scheduled
3. When user goes out of app, the timer is also saved in shared preferences so next time user comes back, the timer is resumed.
4. once the timer finishes, notification is displayed

If you have any confusion do let me know.

Comment: Amazing, I am going to try it....but I have just seen that it works with firebase, so my question is: does it work without an internet connection?

Comment: The firebase is used to save projects and Work logs to provide analytics. It works offline too, and syncs with firebase once connection is active. However if you want to make it fully offline, you can do so with modifications. Timer itself doesn't require firebase or internet. IT is only for keeping record of Projects and work logs I am using the firebase features.

Comment: Hi! I am a beginner in flutter so I can't understand the code of your project. I created a new Flutter project with a TextField and a FlatButton where you can set and start the timer. I created a `void` function called `createTimer()` with a _TODO_ comment in it. Please, can you help me inside that project? I give you the GitHub link: [link] (https://github.com/Anon-65535/SimpleBackgroundTimer)